# KDB: How do I perform a minus on 2 Lists

Tags: kdb

Input:

```
a: 1 2 3 4 5 
b: 5 2 6 7
```

What operation do I need to do to remove all elements of b in a?

Expected Output:

```
1 3 4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the keyword you are looking for is `except`, like so:

```
q)c: a except b
q)c
    1 3 4
```

`Except` returns all elements of its left argument that are absent from the right argument.

Comment: Thank you. I'm having a hard time finding resource about this.

Comment: Here is the current available resource from Kx, you can find most built-in list operations on this websites. https://code.kx.com/q4m3/A_Built-in_Functions/#a28-except

Comment: If you are interested in learning more kdb+, you should check out AquaQ Analytics kdb+ online bootcamp- the free taster course is available here: https://kdbtraining.aquaq.co.uk/shop/kdb-taster       Disclaimer: I am an employee of AquaQ Analytics.

Answer (score 3):

The `except` function will remove items in one list from another.

```
q) a except b
1 3 4
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `except` is the answer here as mentioned by the others. Further, it's worth spending the time to investigate what `except` is actually doing under the covers as it will often help to better understand how kdb/q operates in general. Inspecting `except` you can see

```
q)except
k){x@&~x in y}
```

which translates in kdb/q to

```
q)a where not a in b
1 3 4
```

Again, you should still use `except` but knowing how it is achieved is useful